# GitLab runner can not resolve host when running pipeline

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a dockerized GitLab and GitLab Runner installation, with following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
    container_name: gitlab
    restart: always
    hostname: gitlab
    ports:
      - "45022:22"
      - "45080:80"
      - "45443:443"
    volumes:
      - /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
      - /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab

  python-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    container_name: python-runner
    hostname: python-runner
    volumes:
      - /srv/python-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - CI_SERVER_URL=http://gitlab/ci
      - RUNNER_TOKEN=myTokenCode
      - RUNNER_DESCRIPTION=Python 2.7.14
      - RUNNER_EXECUTOR=docker
      - DOCKER_IMAGE=python:2.7.14
    restart: always
```

I have registered the runner:

```
docker exec -it python-runner gitlab-runner register \
    --non-interactive \
    --url "http://gitlab/" \
    --registration-token "${GITLAB_REGISTRATION_TOKEN}" \
    --description "Python 2.7.14" \
    --executor "docker" \
    --docker-image python:2.7.14
```

The runner is listed in the Runners list:

[image]

I can ping the `gitlab` host from the `python-runner`:

```
» docker exec -it python-runner bash
root@python-runner:/# ping gitlab
PING gitlab (172.20.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from gitlab.gitlab_default (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.112 ms
64 bytes from gitlab.gitlab_default (172.20.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.055 ms
^C
--- gitlab ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.055/0.083/0.112/0.029 ms
```

But when running the pipeline, it fails:

```
`fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab/group/project.git/': Could not resolve host: gitlab
```

How is this possible? How can this be solved?

### EDIT

It seems the architecture that I am creating is the following:

- gitlab running in `gitlab` docker container
- gitlab runner running in `python-runner` docker container
- docker-compose creates a private network `gitlab_default` (`gitlab` is the name of the project), and both the `gitlab` and `python-runner` containers can reach it other, by IP and by name.
- the `python-runner` uses the `docker` executor to spawn containers during CI (in the host?), based on `python:2.7.14` as defined. I do not know how gitlab names these containers, let's call it `ci-job`
- the project is cloned in this `ci-job` container, by issuing a `git clone`. This fails because the `ci-job` container can not reach the `gitlab` container, since it is probably in a different network (`default` network?)

I have tried to force the `python-runner` to spawn containers in the same `gitlab_default` network, by using `--docker-network-mode gitlab_default` flag as follows:

```
docker exec -it python-runner gitlab-runner register \
    --non-interactive \
    --tag-list python-2.7.14 \
    --url "http://gitlab" \
    --registration-token "$(GITLAB_REGISTRATION_TOKEN)" \
    --name "Python 2.7.14" \
    --executor "docker" \
    --docker-image python:2.7.14 \
    --docker-network-mode gitlab_default
```

But it still does not work. I am not sure if that's the right flag, since it is [poorly documented](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/executors/docker/executor_docker.go#L648).

Two questions:

1. How can I see the containers that the executor is creating when running CI? Can I enter them and do some debugging there?
2. What is the relevant parameter to ensure that the containers spawned by the docker executor are in the same network as the `gitlab` container?

### EDIT2

After some idle time, my jobs started working. It seems configuring `--docker-network-mode` did indeed work as expected.

Comment: Just off the top of my head from an issue I had a while back, you might need: `http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab:group/project.git/` (note the semi-colon instead of slash)

Comment: @Rekovni thanks, but that's not it. I have tested removing the trailing slash, but there is no change. The clone URL provided by gitlab itself has the same format: `http://gitlab/group/project.git`

Comment: @Rekovni: I would say this has something to do with the fact that the `git clone` command does not happen in the runner itself, but in the [executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html), which is itself a docker container (running in the host I assume, although I see no traces of it when doing `docker ps -a`)

Comment: and how does your gitlab-ci.yaml look like? mounting docker.sock to your runner is very dangerous. I can recommend dind https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor

Comment: Well, mounting docker.sock is [described](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html) in the official Dokumentation.

Comment: @MazelTov [here](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) is a blog entry by the author of `did` advising against using `did` in CI systems. No idea if that is relevant today.

Comment: @MazelTov [another](https://getintodevops.com/blog/the-simple-way-to-run-docker-in-docker-for-ci) blog entry advising using the host docker engine via a mounted `/var/run/docker.sock`. I wonder what is the official recommendation on this ...

Comment: its nice article, but i am using `dind` also from documentation with overlay filesystem https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#using-the-gitlab-container-registry , i like my approach because when i start my pipeline it is always in clean independent environment, but if you mount the socket the pipelines might interfere with each other?

Comment: fyi https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/17769#note_12193881

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with gitlab-runner not able to resolve host names. But we use Gitlab running on Debian server (not docker installation) and runners in Google Cloud connected with VPN.

What worked for me was to add dns addresses to the runners config.toml, like this:

```
  [runners.docker]
    dns = ["dns-1-ip", "dns-2-ip"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue (docker-compose based setup, both web and runner are running in the same network, but executor -CI jobs- are not). As stated in

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section

you can specify a docker network the executor containers will run in:

```
[runners.docker]
  network_mode = "the_network_docker-compose_created_for_this_project"
```

With this, my executors can clone from `http://web/`, where `web` is the name of the service that runs gitlab web-ui.

Comment: This won't work if you are using a GitLab Omnibus installation.